# bootstrap: grid system failed to put all columns into a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

In my webapp project, I use Bootstrap as the frond end frame. And there is one issue which is confusing for me. The HTML code is as following:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="candidatecity">Cities</label>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-options="city for city in avaiablecities" ng-model="selectedCity" id="candidatecity" ></select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group col-lg-2">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchcity" placeholder = "Search City">
        </div>

        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="period">Time Period</label>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <select class="form-control"  ng-options="period for period in avaiableperiod" ng-model="selectedperiod" id="period"></select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clickSendRequest()">Get Data</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

But the result is as following:
[image]

The confusing point is that all the columns width add together is just 12, which follows the grid system rules.But why it failed to  place these  components in a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <div class="input-group">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="input-group col-lg-2">
  ...
</div>
```

Check the result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="candidatecity">Cities</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <select class="form-control" ng-options="city for city in avaiablecities" ng-model="selectedCity" id="candidatecity" ></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchcity" placeholder = "Search City">
      </div>
    </div>

    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="period">Time Period</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <select class="form-control"  ng-options="period for period in avaiableperiod" ng-model="selectedperiod" id="period"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clickSendRequest()">Get Data</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `input-group` class. If you remove it, the elements will fit in a row:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="candidatecity">Cities</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <select class="form-control" ng-options="city for city in avaiablecities" ng-model="selectedCity" id="candidatecity" ></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchcity" placeholder = "Search City">
    </div>

    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="period">Time Period</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <select class="form-control"  ng-options="period for period in avaiableperiod" ng-model="selectedperiod" id="period"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clickSendRequest()">Get Data</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

After that, you will need to properly style your search icon.